# PHP client side Digest authentication with qop=auth-int

Tags: php, digest

Does anyone know any PHP library for connecting remote servers that use Digest authentication method with qop=auth-int?
Or, if not, now should I build the A2 for the result? It says in RFC 2617 that I need to use an entity body, but what is this? I am just sending a GET request, it does not have any body at all.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the answer to your question too, for requests other than GET. 
Perheps you could use something like:

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

I have not tested if it works, but looking at [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164073/what-is-entity-body-for-digest-authentication) it would make sence to me that it should.

Note that this stream can only be read once [[1]](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) so if you need it again elsewhere you should reuse the $entityBody variable.

Answer (score 1):

[From my answer of a similar question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664957/client-part-of-the-digest-authentication-using-php-post-to-web-service/)

I implemented the client-side Digest Authentication in PHP with cURL recently. Here's the full code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');

$url = "https://api.example.com/ws.asmx/do";
$username = "username";
$password = "pwd";
$post_data = array(
        'fieldname1' => 'value1',
        'fieldname2' => 'value2'
  );

$options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // for https
        CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $username . ":" . $password,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_DIGEST,
        CURLOPT_POST           => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => http_build_query($post_data) 
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

try {
  $raw_response  = curl_exec( $ch );

  // validate CURL status
  if(curl_errno($ch))
      throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), 500);

  // validate HTTP status code (user/password credential issues)
  $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if ($status_code != 200)
      throw new Exception("Response with Status Code [" . $status_code . "].", 500);

} catch(Exception $ex) {
    if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);
    throw new Exception($ex);
}

if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);

echo "raw response: " . $raw_response; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a GET request, you shouldn't need auth-int. If your service requires it, you can assume an empty entity-body (thus you can just do md5("") for this part of the A2 hash).