# What is "entity-body" for Digest Authentication?

Tags: html, authentication, digest-authentication

I am integrating digest authentication and am seeing "entity-body" in the document below (for auth-int authentication)?  Is this the HTML header and body?  Or is it just the HTML header portion?

http://freeradius.org/rfc/rfc4590.html
http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2069

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Entity” is an HTTP concept here. The [HTTP 1.1 glossary](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec1.html#sec1.3) defines it as “The information transferred as the payload of a request or response. An entity consists of metainformation in the form of entity-header fields and content in the form of an entity-body, as described in [section 7](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7).”

Thus, the entity body consists, for example, an entire HTML document, from the document type declaration (if present) down to the end tag `</html>`. The entity headers are HTTP headers, outside the HTML document.

Comment: @AdamJenča it says "it is computed before any transfer encoding is applied by the sender", so should not be the gzipped content?

Comment: Sorry for that, English is my second languge.  I meant the content the  gzip algorithm was    applied to, not the actual result of compression.